# a proper subspace $V$ of $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ such that $V^\perp=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ be the vector space of all  square-integrable functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The inner product is $(f,g)=\int fg d\mu$. I want to find a proper subspace $V$ of $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ such that $V^\perp=0$. Is it possible?

Comment: Any proper dense subspace will do. For some measures, the space is finite-dimensional, then it's not possible. If $L^2(\Omega,\mu)$ is infinite-dimensional, it is always possible.

Comment: What is your definition of a subspace? Some people take it to mean a vector subspace that is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Daniel Fischer, you can take the subspace of step functions.